# Vue is not Firing on Json Update for the second time

Tags: json, vue.js, axios

I am new to Vue.js. Here I am trying to implement rendering of some JSON objects returning from my Restful api.  When I call `allListing(streamid)` from some control, I need to render changed JSON that is received from the API. After spending whole day, I thought of asking here.

Thanks in advance.

```js
callListing(1);

function callListing(streamid) {
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        info: []

      }
    },
    created() {
      axios
        .get('https://localhost:44367/api/listing_institution/byselector/t/' + streamid + '/1')
        .then(response => {
          this.info = response.data,
            console.log(response);

        })
    }
  })
}

function fireListing(streamid) {
  callListing(streamid);
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="dt in info">
    {{dt}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the control?  External to the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Vue.set to make your data reactive.

Vue.set is a tool that allows us to add a new property to an already reactive object. Read more about Vue.set [here](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/so-what-actually-is-vue-set#:%7E:text=set%20.,new%20property%20is%20ALSO%20reactive.).

So, you need to do very few fixes to your code.

Instead of-

```
this.info = response.data,
```

Do like-

```
Vue.set(this.info, 0, response.data);

// It takes three params-
//   1. The element inside which we want to update
//   2. The index where we want to put updated response.
//   3. Response
```

You can check out this example for reference-
[CodeSandBox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-framework-lf902?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: If he intends to retrieve an array from the api, `set` isn't useful.  In that case setting the data directly to `this.info` makes the most sense.  It will replace the empty array, reactively.

Comment: Yeah, agree, but as he is trying to update JSON every time by passing an id to the function from some control that is not updating, so in that case set will be helpful. and if he is trying to update the whole array, the problem should not occur (as you said correctly.)